# mapping fails on multiple form post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, model-binding

I am POSTing two forms on submit.

In my MVC application I have `EmailReportVM` class. This class has a variable called `criteria`, which is of type `StatsCriteria`.

When I post the forms, all the variable in `EmailReporVM` get mapped except `criteria`.

`EmailReportVM`  has the same variables as `frmSendEmail` and 
`StatsCriteria` has the same variables as `frmPostToEmailReports`

What should I do to make this work.

**Caller.js** :

```
$("#frmSendEmail").validate({
    onfocusout: true,
    submitHandler: function (form) {

    //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   
    $.post(url, $("#frmSendEmail, #frmPostToEmailReports").serialize(), function (data) {
        //do something    
    });
}
```

**Controller** :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmailReportVM report)
{
    // Here the report object which is of type EmailReportVM has values for all the variables except criteria . 
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            ....................          
        }                       
    }
}
```

**EmailReportVM.cs** :

```
public class EmailReportVM
{
    #region Constructors and Methods
    public EmailReportVM() {  }
    #endregion

    #region Properties and Fields
    public string from { get; set; }  
    public string to{ get; set; }
    public string Cc{ get; set; }
    public string Bcc{ get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public StatsCriteria criteria { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

**StatsCriteria** :

```
public class StatsCriteria
{
    #region Constructors and Methods
    public StatsCriteria() { }
    public string Params { get; set; }
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNum { get; set; }
    public string AgentFullName { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You should use proper naming for your form element to assign the criteria properties. Remember this is a not a normal property of a class and a class object within a class. Hence to set value inside this object you should provide qualified name to your html elements. E.g. **Input control name for Params** Should be **criteria.Params** in html

Comment: Thank you. tried it but no luck.

Comment: @BumbleBee - Can we see the view please?  I'm interested to see how these forms are arranged.

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct model binding to assign value to complex object.

Check this and let me know if you need any help with code

**http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/**

Comment: Have you had a look at link?